# Dealing with OCR import

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr

I am trying to import below commands in jupyter:

```
from ocr import characters
from ocr.normalization import word_normalization, letter_normalization
# Helpers
from ocr.helpers import implt, resize, img_extend
```

but receive error :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocr'.
Tried finding reasons but could not find anything as ocr package.What am i missing.

Comment: Did you install the module via pip?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install ocr` or `pip3 install ocr` in terminal and try to import it again.

Personally, I recommend the using the module Pytesseract instead.  It can be installed via pip: `pip install pytesseract` or `pip3 install pytesseract`

```
import pytesseract as ptr
print(ptr.image_to_string("image.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the package via pip.
Go to the terminal and type:

```
pip install ocr
```

Or:

```
pip3 install ocr
```

Or try to find the conda command.
Than execute the script

Comment: If it don't works fine, try to uninstall and reinstall python checking that pip is installed. Maybe this library needs something special or works only in a virtual enviroment. Try to create the enviroment with app like pycharm, and then install the library via pip